# How to create in SAS a ranking on a specific range of rows?

Tags: loops, sas, macros, ranking

I need to create a check of how many times the value I have in a given line is less than the last 5 lines dynamically. In excel I can use the formula =COUNTIF(C2:C6;"<="&C2) but I don't know how to do in SAS. Follow the dataset example:

```
data mydataset;
input var_1 datevar date9. value rank_5;
format datevar date9.;
datalines;
1 30DEC2020 -0.008855155 1 /* excel example (=COUNTIF(C2:C6;"<="&C2)) */
1 29DEC2020 -0.003152585 2 /* excel example (=COUNTIF(C3:C7;"<="&C3)) */
1 28DEC2020 0.026537217 4 /* excel example (=COUNTIF(C4:C8;"<="&C4)) */
1 23DEC2020 0.007170795 3
1 22DEC2020 0.007222587 4
1 21DEC2020 -0.021208226 1
1 18DEC2020 0.047811448 5
1 17DEC2020 0.003378378 3
1 16DEC2020 0.006118287 3
1 15DEC2020 -0.000679348 3
1 14DEC2020 -0.012743125 2
1 11DEC2020 0.013596193 4
1 10DEC2020 0.012388162 4
1 09DEC2020 -0.030687125 1
1 08DEC2020 -0.003324468 2
1 07DEC2020 0.01759134 4
1 04DEC2020 -0.001351351 3
1 03DEC2020 -0.006044325 2
1 02DEC2020 0.004723347 2
1 01DEC2020 0.020661157 3
1 30NOV2020 -0.02811245 1
1 27NOV2020 0.009459459 1
2 30DEC2020 -0.004536617 2
2 29DEC2020 -0.003229974 3
2 28DEC2020 -0.003219575 3
2 23DEC2020 -0.015842839 1
2 22DEC2020 0.010890455 4
2 21DEC2020 -0.009517766 2
2 18DEC2020 0.007028754 4
2 17DEC2020 0.013601036 5
2 16DEC2020 -0.020304569 1
2 15DEC2020 0.000634921 2
2 14DEC2020 0.000635324 2
2 11DEC2020 0.001909612 2
2 10DEC2020 -0.000636132 1
2 09DEC2020 0.00319081 3
2 08DEC2020 0.001918159 2
2 07DEC2020 0.003851091 2
2 04DEC2020 0.008414239 3
2 03DEC2020 -0.003225806 2
2 02DEC2020 0.010430248 3
2 01DEC2020 0.031607263 3
2 30NOV2020 0.00472973 2
2 27NOV2020 -0.012016021 1
run;
```

I tried several approach but none worked well.

Comment: Are you trying to count by looking AHEAD in the file?  It is much easier to look BACK.  It is much easier to remember something than it is to predict the future.  So first step is probably to reverse the sort order of the observations.

Comment: What do you mean by C2 and C3?   By "C" do you mean VALUE?  And by 2 and 3 do you mean 2 and 3 days into the future?

Answer (score 0):

`SORT` the data by ascending date and use `LAG` functions or a ring array to compare the value of the current date to the values of previous dates.

Example:

Your data seems to have a grouping variable (`var1`) so you will want to account for that.  A ring array uses modulo arithmetic to calculate the index.

```
proc sort data=have;
  by group date;
run;

data want(drop=_i_);
  set have;
  by group;

  array v(0:4) _temporary_;
  if first.group then call missing(of v(*));

  /* count how many times one of the previous 5 values is > current value */
  do _i_ = lbound(v) to hbound(v);
    rank = sum(rank, value < v(_i_) );
  end;

  v(mod(_n_,5)) = value;
run;

proc sort data=want;
  by group date;
run;
```

You can also use +1/-1 to calculate the result

```
  index = mod(_n_,5);
  if value < v(index) then rank=sum(rank,1);
  else 
  if value > v(index) then rank=sum(rank,-1);

  v(index) = value;
```